# Trying to find an child image element passed using "this" in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access an image that is passed into an event handler using this in jQuery.

So "this" in this case would be a div or li that contains an img tag within the div or li.

I've tried the follow accessors:

$(this).attr(), 
 $(this).('.imgClassName').attr(), 
 $(this: img).attr(), 
 $(this.imgClassName).attr()

and none of those worked. Here is my script:

```
        var closedText = 'Show All';
        var openedText = 'Hide All';
        var helpExpand = '/images/expand.png';
        var helpCollapse = '/images/collapse.png';

$('li.helpList: a').click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function () {

                if (faqClosed) {
                    $(this).attr({
                        src: helpExpand,
                        title: openedText,
                        alt: openedText
                    });
                } else {
                    $(this).attr({
                        src: helpCollapse,
                        title: closedText,
                        alt: closedText
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

This does not work. However, this does work (for my Hide/Show all):

```
$('#showAll').click(function () {
            if (faqClosed) { // closed
                $('li.helpList: div').show('fast'); faqClosed = false;
                $('#showAll').text(openedText);
                $(".helpToggle").attr({
                    src: helpExpand,
                    title: openedText,
                    alt: openedText
                });
            } else { // opened
                $('li.helpList: div').hide('fast'); faqClosed = true;
                $('#showAll').text(closedText);
                $(".helpToggle").attr({
                    src: helpCollapse,
                    title: closedText,
                    alt: closedText
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

$('li.helpList: div') is the container for an open/closed item. Within that is an img tag with a little arrow. Here is the HTML for a container:

```
             <li class="helpList">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/images/collapse.png" class="helpToggle" alt="Contraer" />How do I do stuff?
                </a>
                <div class="helpContent">To do stuff, please do something.</div>
            </li>
```

[UPDATE]

Here is my test script, which alerts open or close depeneding on the state. This currently works, but it still can not find the image (the collapse/expand.png file does not hide, and it never changes)

```
 // Wire up hide/show to a.click event: 
        $('li.helpList: a').click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function () {
                if (faqClosed) {
                    alert('closed');
                    $(this).find('.helpToggle').hide();
                    $(this).find('img').attr({
                        src: helpExpand,
                        title: openedText,
                        alt: openedText
                    });

                    faqClosed = false;

                } else {

                    alert('open');
                    $(this).find('.helpToggle').show();
                    $(this).find('img').attr({
                        src: helpCollapse,
                        title: closedText,
                        alt: closedText
                    });

                    faqClosed = true;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with an `a` tag.  You call `.next()` which gets the next sibling (the `div`) and then call `slideToggle()` on that.

`this` in that context is the `div`, which doesn't contain the image.

If you want to search within the `a` tag, store a reference to it before you call `slideToggle()`, then use it as the context (second parameter) for your selector.

```
$('li.helpList: a').click(function () {
     var anchor = this;
     ... // snipped for brevity
     $('img', anchor).attr(...)
```

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/SZWnn/) to illustrate it (apologies for the image, it's the only one I had available).

Comment: Hahaha - Wonder Dog to the Rescue!!! Very cool - I'm impressed. This was a killer answer *bows humbly*. I see what you're saying, "this" was the div, until I called next() - at which point it increments the level of this for the entire scope of the function. Very interesting. Thanks for the demo - jsfiddle huh? I will start using this site for my snippets. /highfive

Comment: @Shawn: Haha! Yes, I really shouldn't be apologising for enlisting the help of the amazing Wonder Dog! In your example `this` was the `a`, until you called `next()` which gets the next sibling (the `div`). Any functions you then call against the object returned by `next()` are run against the matched elements: in this case the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$(this).find('img')...
```

Gets all images that are children (any depth) of this.

Comment: I just tried adding $(this).find('img').show() and $(this).find('img').hide() to if/else statements (respectively) for easy debugging and it didn't work. It does not touch the images. I also tried it with the class name. In fact it does not hide any images... Maybe "this" doesn't have the img in scope? I'm not sure how that could be. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe I missed this in your initial code... is this your real code? `$('li.helpList: a')` I don't think you need or want the colon `:` you want `$('li.helpList a')`

Comment: MMmmmm I didn't notice that. It very well could be the problem. I'll check now and reply with my results. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't help. I need the :a in order to find the element which is clicked. I know it works because I added an "alert()" to each if/else case and it alerts open/close correctly. In my <a> there is an <image> tag, so it should find the img in "this". I will update the code block with this test code.

Comment: hmm I need to go check up on my selector syntax because I have no idea what the ": a" even does.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $(this).find('.imgClassName').attr()?